# How to check whether a path is in another path using Pathlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

I'm trying to find a readable way to check whether a path is within another path across more than a single level.  I can check the immediate parent, but not beyond that so far.

```
import pathlib
path1 = pathlib.Path('/a/b')
path2 = pathlib.Path('/a/b/c/d')
path2.parent == path1  # <-- this is False, expected.
path2 in path1  # <-- this is False, UNEXPECTED.
```

#### How can I check for presence of one path in another?

Or is the best option to devolve to string comparisons and `startwith` checks on absolute paths?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Path instances have a [`parents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parents) attribute that contains a sequence of all ancestors. You can test whether one path is 'in another path' by testing whether it is an ancestor of the other path.

Using your example paths, this is as simple as:

```py
path1 in path2.parents
```

Comment: This is helpful and satisfies the question as originally scoped, so accepting. This particular situation requires that I only go part of the way up the parents (e.g. all the parents are too general), so I might have to devolve to strings and `startswith`. I guess I would love `in` operator support for something closer to this need.

Comment: @tarabyte if you want to go up only a particular number of levels, `parents` supports slicing (since Python 3.10; for lower 3.x you will have to index explicitly). E.g. `path2.parents[:2]` would get you a sequence containing `/a/b/c` and `/a/b`. That might help you control how far up you are willing to go?